# What is BrowserSubprocessPath?

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have CefSharp-master project with which is Built on Chromium- 31.0.1650.57. All is working fine and perfect. But while Initializing `settings.BrowserSubprocessPath` is set to an executable.

What is this `BrowserSubprocessPath`? what happen if I avoid this?

I am Initializing Cef as:

```
    public static void Init()
    {
        var settings = new CefSettings();

        settings.UserAgent = "MyBrowser";         
        if (!Cef.Initialize(settings))
        {
            if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("--type=renderer"))
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

This is working fine, Only after sometime browser window goes blank.What is the reason behind this.

Comment: There is a very similar question/issue in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/456

Comment: Does #456 answer your question? Also ... please please extend this question so it has "MVCE" as linked to in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269536/210723. E.g are you seeing this with `CefSharp.Wpf.Example` or `CefSharp.WinForms.Example`?

Comment: Yes I m using CefSharp.WinForms.Example.

Answer (score 1):

When you set SingleProcess = false you should define sub-process executable file for it:

http://xilium.bitbucket.org/cefglue/doc/html/E3568E23.htm

So you can set SingleProcess = true (which is not recommended in production)
or set it to a sub-process file like cefclient.exe